# Do I need to add a library in order to use jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am new to web development
and I tries using a simple jquery function in my web page
but it wont work. Do I need to import any library in my code ?

```
<title>Sample Code</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
</head>
```

### javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('container').fadeOut(5000);
});
```

### CSS

```
#container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #92e9ff;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;   
}

#box1, #box2, #box3, #box4, #box5, #box6{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #404479;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;      
}

p{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #ffffff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: normal;
}
```

Comment: You need to include library `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
`

Comment: If you want to start with jquery, read this http://jquery.com/

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/ <-- read this !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to include jQuery library. Even you can use CDN or download a copy.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```